# How to find the average value when group by multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have following two temporary tables, #dates and #availability, and one datetime varaible,     @startdate.

The variable is:

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2016-12-20'
```

The column and data of #dates is:

```
Date
-------
2016-12-20
2016-12-21
2016-12-22
```

The Column and data of #availability is:

```
GroupId     Date           StatusId     Price
-----------------------------------------------
111       2016-12-20        1           200
111       2016-12-21        1           100
111       2016-12-22        1           500
111       2016-12-22        1           300
222       2016-12-20        4           100 
222       2016-12-21        1           200
222       2016-12-22        1           200
333       2016-12-20        1           100
333       2016-12-22        4           200
```

Table #dates shows the date range the customer will stay in the hotel room, and these dates must(should) be consecutive

Table #availability is the availability data I got from other tables.

My goal is to show the **average price** for **each valid group**.

The restrictions are:

1. For the start date, the StatusId must be 1; otherwise, the StatusId can be 1 or 4(but can't be other number, like 2 and 3)
   That means GroupId 2 has been removed from our result here.
2. If the group didn't have complete price info for the date range, we will remove it.
   GroupId 3 doesn't have price info of 2016-12-21, and it will be removed.
3. If any day has multiple price, we choose the minimum price for that day.
   That means Group 1 will use the following data to calculate average price:

   2016-12-20  -->     $200

   2016-12-21  -->     $100

   2016-12-22  -->     $300

   Then, show the final average price: $(200 + 100 + 300) / 3 days = $200

I started with this,

```
Select GroupId,Date
From #availability
Group by GroupId, Date
```

but can't figure out how to tell whether the Date number is matched the #dates table, and the startdate status must be 1 in #availability for each group.

Comment: What's the use of the `@startdate` variable?

Comment: You can take it as criteria in "Where" if you want. It is just like supplementary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it.  Here is 1 way that doesn't require dates to be consecutive and does NOT rely on a Cartesian join between dates and GroupIds, which should help performance.

```
;WITH cteMinPricePerDay AS (
    SELECT
       d.Date
       ,GroupId
       ,StatusId
       ,MIN(Price) as Price
       ,COUNT(d.Date) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId) GroupDateCount
       ,dc.DateCount
    FROM
       #date d
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) as DateCount FROM #date) dc
       LEFT JOIN #availability a
       ON d.Date = a.Date
       AND NOT(d.Date = @startdate AND a.StatusId <> 1)
    GROUP BY
       d.Date
       ,GroupId
       ,StatusId
       ,dc.DateCount
)

SELECT
    GroupId
    ,Date
    ,StatusId
    ,Price
    ,AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId) as AvgPrice
FROM
    cteMinPricePerDay
WHERE
    GroupDateCount = DateCount
```

Steps/description

- create a group by to get the minimum price per day per GroupId
- in same query also CROSS APPLY a count of the dates from the #dates table to be used to determine if a group has all of the dates represented.
- generate a count of dates per group
- Next select from the Common Table Expression where the group has the same count of days as the #date table
- Add a AVG() window function to calculate the AveragePrice

And for good measure here is a method using the Cartesian join between distinct groups and dates.

```
;WITH cteDistinctGroups AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupId
    FROM
       #availability
)

, cteMinPricePerDay AS (
    SELECT
       d.Date
       ,g.GroupId
       ,MIN(a.Price) as Price
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Date IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GroupId) as GroupMissingDateCount
    FROM
       #date d
       CROSS JOIN cteDistinctGroups g
       LEFT JOIN #availability a
       ON d.Date = a.Date
       AND g.GroupId = a.GroupId
       AND NOT(d.Date = @startdate AND a.StatusId <> 1)
    GROUP BY
       d.Date
       ,a.Date
       ,g.GroupId
)

SELECT
    GroupId
    ,Date
    ,Price
    ,AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId) as AveragePrice
FROM
    cteMinPricePerDay
WHERE
    GroupMissingDateCount = 0
```

Comment: It's really close to what I want. Thank you! I am thinking about how to filter out the result, which its statusId of start date is equal to 1, and statusId of other non-startdate can be 1 or 4.

Comment: hmmm okay that is where we can use your variable and test if it is the startdate in the join condition.. give me a second and I will update I just want to test and add a case/2 to the test data to appropriately test it

Comment: @user3174976 I updated the query just change the ON condition of a.StatusId = 1 TO -  NOT(d.Date = startdateVar AND a.StatusId <> 1)   Having the variable saved us from having to generate another common table expression (or derived table) to identify the oldest date

Comment: your welcome.  Thanks for accepting the answer if you want to upvote it too that would be great. cheers